# How can I move an 80-bit floating point number with double precision from memory to XMM0 in AT&T assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, long-double

I've written an AT&T assembly function to calculate an integral. I need to pass it as a return value as it's called by code written in C. I've successfully managed to return it as a single precision `float` and a double precision `double`. But I know I can calculate it in 80-bit double extended precision and I'd love to pass it to C.

Let's assume the value I want to pass is pointed to in an FPU register pointed by TOP. Here's how I call functions.

For float:

```
//C
double  integ_fo=integ_asm_fpu_fl();

#asm
...  
fstps   max        # Fpu STore and Pop Short <- short for 32-bit
movss   max, %xmm0 # MOVe Scalar Single precision
```

For double:

```
//C
double  integ_do=integ_asm_fpu_do();

#asm
...  
fstpl   max        # Fpu STore and Pop Long <- long for 64-bit
movsd   max, %xmm0 # MOVe Scalar Dingle precision
```

My question is now: how can I complete following code, so that C can read `long double` from the `%XMM0` register.

For long double:

```
//C
long double  integ_lo=integ_asm_fpu_lo();

#asm
...  
fstpt   max        # FPU Store and Pop exTended <- extended for 80-bit
```

What should I do after that? How would I move 80 bits from `max` to `%XMM0`?

Comment: I'd love to compare precision and execution time of my code for single, double and double-extended precision mode. While I can run code in double-extended and count clocks, I would also like to print (via 'printf("%Ld,integral);' and validate result.

Comment: Which calling convention applies here? The rules for long double differ. For x64 linux, you return them in ST(0)

Comment: Thx, harold. Answer me, so I can mark your answer.

Comment: You can't move an 80-bit floating point number to XMM0. The XMM registers only support 32-bit and 64-bit floating numbers. As harlod said you need to follow the calling convention for your operating system which should provide some other mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. Please, answer question, @harold, so i can mark your answer.

Comment: I don't really have anything useful to cite for a proper answer, also are you actually using x64 linux? (that was just a total guess on my part)

Comment: Yes, @harold, I am using x64 Linux. Sorry, I did not specify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your premise is wrong:

> how can I complete following code, so that C can read long double from
>   the %XMM0 register.

The sysv abi does not return `long double` in `xmm0` register, but `st0`.
The relevant part of the [documentation](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf):

> The 64-bit mantissa of arguments of type long double belongs to class
>   X87, the 16-bit exponent plus 6 bytes of padding belongs to class
>   X87UP.
>
> If the class is X87UP, the value is returned together with the
>   previous X87 value in %st0.

Apparently you already have the value in `st0` so you don't have to do anything just leave it there, meaning delete the `fstpt` in your example.